# using a canvas in gtkmm application

Tags: canvas, gtk, gtkmm

I am starting to try out some gui libs with c++ interface.

Actually I try some examples with gtkmm. Simple examples work, but now I search for a canvas. I found libgnomecanvasmm with seems to be part of libgnomemm with seems to be usable under gtkmm I hope!

But I have not found a simple example how I can add the libgnomecanvas with the gtkmm interface.

Could someone help me with a simple prog with draw a single line in a window with contains only the canvas as an example.

It seems terrible hard to get any real working examples. There seems to be only the class diagrams without any documentation. I am searching for days now but couldn't find any usable code.

Edit:
Ok, I will check for goocanvasmm. The packages I could install have no example code. Also the net did not offer an example!? Can anyone point me to one? The documentation I found is nearly empty, only the doxygen generated class hierarchy is in. Functions without descriptions are *very* helpful :-)

Comment: Do you actually need a fully-featured canvas (ie. one that does drawing of state for you) or just a way to draw a custom widget?

Comment: I want to have some "active items" in the canvas if possible. It would be nice to have something like tk-canvas. In tk it is also possible to give graphic shapes mouse events and so on. If there is some "full featured canvas" available, it would be nice :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libgnomecanvas and libgnomecanvasmm are deprecated and have not been maintained for years. There is still no official replacement, but goocanvas (wrapped by goocanvasmm) is fairly popular and sane.

However, there are examples in the libgnomecanvasmm tarball. But I wouldn't touch it now (I once maintained it).

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the examples in the package. I didn't find anything in the web but yes, the package contains a simple example. After calling Canvas::init my code works :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should try [goocanvasmm](http://developer.gnome.org/goocanvasmm/stable/), the C++ bindings to [GooCanvas](https://live.gnome.org/GooCanvas).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your requirements but [papyrus](http://libpapyrus.sourceforge.net/) provides a native GTKmm canvas. gnomecanvas should have been deprecated [some years ago](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/release-team/2009-July/msg00043.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment so here is an answer - thanks for making this question, was useful to get started with the canvas.

There is a [chapter on using the GNOME canvas](http://openbooks.sourceforge.net/books/wga/gnome-canvas.html) in the online book 'Writing GNOME Applications' that goes through everything in detail.

Comment: Can you also post some relevant content from the link?